# Need to pass a URL parameter to web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a MVC app with most controllers of type `System.Web.MVC.Controller`. There is one Web API controller also of type `System.Web.Http.ApiController`.

The Web API controller has an action that needs to accept URL as a parameter, something like this:

```
[HttpGet]       
public HttpResponseMessage Image(string path)
{
    //download and return image using WebClient library
}
```

On the view I would like to use the `Image` action something like

```
<image src="/api/image/?path=/remote/relative/path/someimage.jpg" alt="some description" />
```

I'm using following route template:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "api-image",
    routeTemplate: "/api/image/{path}",
    defaults: new { controller = "WebApiClient", action = "Image" }
);
```

The Image action only gets called for paths like `/api/image/someimage-1.jpg` or `/api/image/someimage-2.jpg`

**Question:**
The `Image` action does not get called for long paths like `/api/image/?path=/remote/relative/path/someimage.jpg`

If I encode the long path with `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`, it simply goes to global Not Found action (configured via web.config).

But if I don't encode it, "Dangerous characters found in path" exception gets thrown.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `*` to the route template:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "api-image",
    routeTemplate: "/api/image/{*path}",
    defaults: new { controller = "WebApiClient", action = "Image" }
);
```

and use it without encoding.